# Burninate [leak]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, burninate-request

The [leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/leak) tag has 1010 questions, most of which are about memory leaks.

The tag-wiki says:

> The [leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/leak) tag refers to a memory leak, which has a very specific meaning with regards to programming.
>
> From the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak):
>
> A memory leak, in computer science (or leakage, in this context), occurs when a computer program consumes memory but is unable to release it back to the operating system. In object-oriented programming, a memory leak happens when an object is stored in memory but cannot be accessed by the running code.

Given the fact that there is already a [memory-leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-leak) tag, with 8104 questions (and a better tag-wiki), this tag seems redundant.

Comment: Why burninate rather than synonymificate?

Comment: I guess that would also work, but we need somebody with score 5 in the tag.

Comment: "_Failed to propose synonym: Reverse synonym leak already proposed on the tag leaks_". Gah.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/leak) tag has been merged into [memory-leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-leaks). And now I'm thinking about leeks.

Comment: `And now I'm thinking about leeks.` - much tastier in a soup.